# Format cells if value matches any value in another sheet column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I have Sheet1 with a bunch of names in column D. I want to format all of Sheet 2 so that if a name in Sheet 2 matches any names in Sheet 1 D column the formatting kicks in.

I have tried a variety of variations of this format 
text contains: 
('Sheet1', !$D:$D)

but cannot seem to get it.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to use VLOOKUP

https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1

To test if column X contains a value Y, use the formula

```
   =NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(Y, X, 1, false)))
```

VLOOKUP fetches values, but returns an error if the value is not found in the target range.

ISERROR returns TRUE if the formula inside it results in an error value.

NOT reverses the result of ISERROR, so that your formula is basically saying "Does range X contain value Y?"

Answer (score 1):

Please select all of Sheet2 then HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet1!$D:$D,A1)>0
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select your formatting, OK, OK.